# Open modal using JavaScript after a certain number of clicks

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a jeopardy-style trivia game and I want to open up a modal at the very end that shows the final score. There are 25 blocks of clues. When you open a clue, you have to select the answer you think is right, and then a modal appears telling you if you were right or wrong along with a button that says "back to board", which takes  you back to the main board.

This back to board button has a class of ".back".

Since there are 25 blocks, I thought of creating a count function that counts how many times the .back button is clicked. After the 25th click, this final modal opens up with the person's final score.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="finalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="finalScore" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-body">
                   <p>Test</p>   
                </div></div></div></div>
```

JS:

```
let count = 0;

function init() {
  count = 0;
  let button = document.getElementByClass("back");
  button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  if (count == 25) {
        $('#finalModal').modal('show');
    };
    
};
};
```

I'm a total newbie when it comes to javascript and modals, so if you have any suggestions on a better way to achieve this, please share!

Comment: It's hard to give advice without understanding the entire context of your app. But generally speaking, this forum is for those seeking answers to specific coding issues, not architectural advice on how to build applications.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to achieve what you want. Perhaps a better/cleaner way to achieve it can be the `onclick` event from HTML. You can find the reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). Something like:

screen.html

```
<button onclick="clickBack()" class="back">
  Back
</button>
```

screen.js

```
let count = 0;

function clickBack() {
  count++; // increment count by 1
  
  if (count === 25) { // triple equals for strict comparison
    $('#finalModal').modal('show');
  }
}
```

**Note**

The triple equals is for strict comparison. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#strict_equality_using)

Answer (score 0):

```
(() => {
  let count = 0;
  document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (++count === 25) {
      $('#finalModal').modal('show');
    }
  });
})();
```

- Don't declare `count` globally, put it inside of an "IIFE" or "closure" (research them and other things below)
- Use arrow functions
- Give your button a (unique) id, not a class
- Use `addEventListener`
- Use the prefix form of incrementing `++count` then use strict triple-equal comparison